# Error method describe failed: 401 unauthorized

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to connect to an RTSP camera using opencv c++ but for this specific camera i am getting the following message whenever i try to connect

**Error method describe failed: 401 unauthorized**

the code i used to connect is as follows:

```
VideoCapture camera;

camera.open("rtsp://ssdadmin:S5D.admin@<IP>:<PORT>/live/221067c3-fa55-4c44-819d-47b54497cfc9", CAP_FFMPEG);
```

where the username is ssdadmin and the password is S5D.admin
and used the correct values for ip and port

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635117) that opencv might need url encoding for the password special characters so i switched the "." character in the password to %2E (S5D%2Eadmin) again same problem. knowing that accessing the same url in vlc without encoding the character works.

what am i missing in the address to get the unauthorized message

Comment: You're probably missing the right password or login id. That's what "unauthorized" means, usually.

Comment: Also could be an OS error when user has unsufficient permissions

Comment: reproduce without opencv, with ffmpeg, from a command line. if that still shows the same error, it's no longer an opencv issue.